# php code of frames not executed in public_html

Tags: php, ubuntu, apache2, public-html

I have a php site main.php in the `public_html` dir, which sources several frames:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>My Site</title>
</head>
<frameset rows="55, *, 0" frameborder="no">
    <frame id='headerFrame' src="headerFrame.php" scrolling="no">
    <frame src="mainPages/a.php">
    <frame src="mainPages/b.php">
</frameset>
</html>
```

The php code tags in main.php (not shown) are executed correctly by the server, but when I review the frame sources in the browser, I see uninterpreted php tags in the html:

headerFrame.php:

```
<?php
include 'base.php';
?>
<html>
...
```

How comes that main.php is interpreted, but headerFrame.php not?
When I move the page to `/var/www/mypage/` this works out all well.

Environment: Ubuntu 12.10, apache2

Comment: Your path for your include is probably wrong. Error reporting would tell you this.

Comment: Do you have /var/www and /var/public_html? Or how does your directory structure look like? There might be an issue with your php configuration, saying that php is executed in /var/www but not in /var/public_html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the error on my own, which is not completely evident in the posted snippet:

There where many includes with relative paths in the php scripts. And relative paths for `include` are handled differently for `/var/www/mypage` and `~/public_html/mypage`.

The former one considers relative paths relative to the running script file location, whereas the latter one handles relative paths relative to the main dir (`~/public_html/mypage`).

As in the latter case the included php files where not found, the php tags where dumped instead of interpreted by the apache server.

I use the default apache2 configuration for Ubuntu 12.10, except that I enabled the userdir.